# Can someone elaborate and explain this kind of code. I would like to know more information on it to build a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is the code example in which I got from https://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=8964  .  I have not found an example in which explains this type of code or how I would import it into SQLite database . After  a little understanding of the code I should be able to work with it.  Language java.

```
~01001~^~0100~^~Butter, salted~^~BUTTER,WITH SALT~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
~01002~^~0100~^~Butter, whipped, with salt~^~BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
~01003~^~0100~^~Butter oil, anhydrous~^~BUTTER OIL,ANHYDROUS~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASCII. The field separators are obvious. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Well as I said, I know nothing about ASCII, so I was assuming this is what it was.  How would I put this code into a SQLite database.  I would have no idea how I would reference them.

Comment: I have never used this format of code within a database.  I actually never used code like this before so I hope you understand where I am coming from.  It is difficult to ask the right question when I really dont know what I am exactly looking at.  Can you elaborate on the code I posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you need to do is write your own parser for this data. I don't know of any android libraries built specifically for this type of parsing but it wouldn't be that hard to do.

Something like, where document is a list of each line of the file.

```
for(string line : document)
    string[] values = line.split("^");
    for(string value : values)
        //Add to database
```

That will give you all the values for each line. It looks as though strings are surrounded by ~~. So to check for string

```
if(value.CharAt(0) == '~' && value.CharAt(value.length -1))
```

and a null value would be

```
if("~~".equals(value))
```

Looking at the document you linked though it appears they don't offer column headings for you so you will have to set these manually for each file you have to parse.

Comment: Should I work with this code over the original code I had posted.  I am trying to understand this a little more.      ~16200~^~CAMPBELL'S BRN SUGAR&BACON FLAV BKD BNS~^69.40^123^3.85^1.92^1.75^23.08^6.2^10.00^31^1.11^^^^362^^^^^0.0^^^^^^^^^^^^0^^^^^^^^^^^^0.385^^^4^130^~.5 cup~^130^~1 serving~^0       The website said this is more suitable for importing into applications.

Comment: They look pretty similar in terms of format. In fact, I can't see a difference but one important thing to note is that areas surrounded by ~ characters are strings and those that aren't are numeric so `^^` and `^~~^` are both null but the second is a string field

Comment: https://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=23634  This is the website in which I am getting the code from. If it helps looking at the descriptions they have for the downloads.  Can you give an example of the column headings?  Ian Sellar

Comment: The link I just posted is a more direct link to the files than the one I posted in the original question.

Comment: So when I click on the link and download the ASCII version it gives me a zip file. Opening the zip it looks like each .txt file in the zip is a different table in the database. None of the .txt files have column headings but they seem pretty well laid out. For all of them the ID primary key is the first field followed by the other fields of the table. I am not a nutritionist so I am not exactly sure what all the fields should be named but if you are familiar with nutrition you should be able to figure it out from the file name and the information in the fields.

Comment: The excel file has headings so you could probably reference that, and the included pdf seems to have the necessary documentation.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try and work with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Its a delimited string/file. Flat file systems use this feature to seperate data, ie into columns. They usually go by /n (new line) for each row. Not a Java guy so Im hoping someone else can explain it with code. You would break up the fields and add them to your database. Hope it helps at least a bit.

Comment: This helps a lot.  I would like some java code but knowing a little information allows me to research it.  I was going off of nothing but the code I posted.  Thank you.